# Not display table SQLite and php

Tags: php, html, display

```
    $table = "<p><table width=\"770px\">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><b>FECHA</b></th>
      <th><b>PRODUCTO</b></th>
      <th><b>CANTIDAD</b></th>
      <th><b>PRECIO</b></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
  <tbody> " . while($res = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC))
         { 
         echo
    "<tr>
      <td>" . $res['fecha'] . "</td>
      <td>" . $res['nombre'] . "</td>
      <td>" . $res['cantidad'] . "</td>
      <td>" . $res['precio_hospital'] . "<br></td>
    </tr>"; 
         }  . "
  </tbody>
</table>";
```

Hello friends, I have a php page that does not allow me to show the table correctly I do not know how to place the while, please can you help me.

works friend, but I want to save the result of this table in a php variable to print it in

```
$ pdf-> writeHTML ($table, true, false, true, false, '');
```

Comment: You need to end your `echo` statement before the `while`, and then call another `echo` after the `while`, you can't concatenate things before and after a loop like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use echo when you are already inside and echo. Try:

```
$output = '<p><table width="770px">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><b>FECHA</b></th>
      <th><b>PRODUCTO</b></th>
      <th><b>CANTIDAD</b></th>
      <th><b>PRECIO</b></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
  <tbody>';

while($res = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) { 
    $output .= '<tr><td>' . $res['fecha']    . '</td>' .
                   '<td>' . $res['nombre']   . '</td>' .
                   '<td>' . $res['cantidad'] . '</td>' .
                   '<td>' . $res['precio_hospital']    . 
               '<br></td></tr>'; 
}
$output .= '</tbody></table>';
```

Comment: works friend, but I want to save the result of this table in a php variable to print it in

$ pdf-> writeHTML ($table, true, false, true, false, '');

Comment: You didn't say that originally. Updated my answer to produce a variable named `$output`.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
$myVar = "<p><table width=\"770px\">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><b>FECHA</b></th>
        <th><b>PRODUCTO</b></th>
        <th><b>CANTIDAD</b></th>
        <th><b>PRECIO</b></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  <tbody> ";

while($res = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) { 
  $myVar .=
    "<tr>
      <td>" . $res['fecha'] . "</td>
      <td>" . $res['nombre'] . "</td>
      <td>" . $res['cantidad'] . "</td>
      <td>" . $res['precio_hospital'] . "<br></td>
    </tr>"; 
}

$myVar .= "</tbody></table></p>";

//echo $myVar; //if you want to see the result
//$pdf->writeHTML ($myVar, true, false, true, false, ''); //to pdf
```

You can't concatenate a control structure to a string. PHP will throw a syntax error.

Edited to use a variable

Comment: works friend, but I want to save the result of this table in a php variable to print it in $ pdf-> writeHTML ($table_result, true, false, true, false, '');